# XML Parsing Error on wordpress website feeds?

Tags: xml, wordpress, rss

I get the following error with the feeds on a [wordpress website](http://projectsilkworm.com/feed/). What is it due to and how can I fix this?

`XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
Location: http://projectsilkworm.com/feed/
Line Number 2, Column 1:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a blank line at the start of your xml feed - Chrome shows the same error when opening the feed. The following line needs to be the first bit of text in your xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

You can either fix the error at source, or `trim` the data before trying to parse it.

The source of the problem is probably either your wordpress theme or a plugin.

Go into your theme folder and edit the `header.php` file - make sure the `<!DOCTYPE` declaration is the first line, and there is no whitespace before it.

If that doesn't work, try deactivating any plugins one by one to see if one of them is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, how can I `trim` the data?

Comment: `trim` was more for if you were writing a script to parse the xml. I've amended my post with instructions on how to fix the feed.

Comment: As I thought, your website also has the blank line - so I think it's caused by the theme you have chosen having the blank line in `header.php`

Comment: ok so I did the changes in the `header.php` file (removed anything before `<!doctype` but it is still the same unfortuntately.

Comment: None of the plugins create the problem too.

Comment: Really? The problem seems to be fixed when I view the feed

Answer (score 0):

I had same type of problem.
I had update wordpress version then It is working fine. 
you can update your wordpress Version.

thanks